# Change key indexing format for nth level of nested array in php

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, nested-loops

I have nth level of nested array with string naming key , I want to convert that in indexing key only for **array of item key**.
i tried it to convert but that conversation only possible for limited level of nested array rather than nth level .

Input array:

```
$input_array= [
    "NOCPL-All -working" => [
            "name" => "NOCPL-All -working",
            "item" => [
                        "apis for web" => [ 
                            "name" => "apis for web",
                            "item" => [
                                    "0" => [
                                            "name" => "update user branch maps"
                                        ]
                            ]
                        ],
                        "update user web" => [ 
                            "name" => "update user web",
                            "item" => [
                                    "0" => [
                                            "name" => "update user"
                                        ],
                                        "1" => [
                                            "name" => "add  user"
                                        ]
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ];
```

### I tried below code to convert indexing of 'item' nested array for limited level

```
function cleanArrayKeys($arr) {
        foreach($arr as $k=>$arr1) {
            if(isset($arr[$k]['item'])) {
                $arr[$k]['item'] = array_values($arr[$k]['item']);
                
                foreach($arr[$k]['item'] as $k1=>$arr2) {
                    if(isset($arr[$k]['item'][$k1]['item'])) {
                        $arr[$k]['item'][$k1]['item'] = array_values($arr[$k]['item'][$k1]['item']);
                        
                        foreach($arr[$k]['item'][$k1]['item'] as $k3=>$arr3) {
                            if(isset($arr[$k]['item'][$k1]['item'][$k3]['item'])) {
                                $arr[$k]['item'][$k1]['item'][$k3]['item'] = array_values($arr[$k]['item'][$k1]['item'][$k3]['item']);
                                
                                foreach($arr[$k]['item'][$k1]['item'][$k3]['item'] as $k4=>$arr4) {
                                    if(isset($arr[$k]['item'][$k1]['item'][$k3]['item'][$k4]['item'])) {
                                        $arr[$k]['item'][$k1]['item'][$k3]['item'][$k4]['item'] = array_values($arr[$k]['item'][$k1]['item'][$k3]['item'][$k4]['item']);
                                        
                                        foreach($arr[$k]['item'][$k1]['item'][$k3]['item'][$k4]['item'] as $k5=>$arr5) {
                                            if(isset($arr[$k]['item'][$k1]['item'][$k3]['item'][$k4]['item'][$k5]['item'])) {
                                                $arr[$k]['item'][$k1]['item'][$k3]['item'][$k4]['item'][$k5]['item'] = array_values($arr[$k]['item'][$k1]['item'][$k3]['item'][$k4]['item'][$k5]['item']);
                                            }
                                        }
                                
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        
        return $arr;
    }

print_r(cleanArrayKeys($input_array));
?>
```

Expected Output :

```
[
    "NOCPL-All -working" => [
            "name" => "NOCPL-All -working",
            "item" => [
                        "0" => [ 
                            "name" => "apis for web",
                            "item" => [
                                    "0" => [
                                            "name" => "update user branch maps"
                                        ],
                                        "1" => [
                                            "name" => "add  user branch maps"
                                        ]
                            ]
                        ],
                        "1" => [ 
                            "name" => "update user web",
                            "item" => [
                                    "0" => [
                                            "name" => "update user"
                                        ]
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a recursion:

```
function aValues(&$arr) {
    if (array_key_exists('item', $arr)) {
        $arr['item'] = array_values($arr['item']);
    } 

    foreach ($arr['item'] as &$el) {
        if (array_key_exists('item', $el)) {
            aValues($el);
        }
    }
}

aValues($input_array);

print_r($input_array);
```

Comment: Big Thank you @Aleksey , it is working for me .
just need to change array_key_exist to array_key_exists